# Android 10 device won't reach one specific web-site?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, android-10, dns

My android 10 device is failing to access one particular website.  All others are fine.  This started happening a few weeks ago.

I have contacted my mobile ISP and they say their systems are working ok.

I have contacted the website support, and they say I am not blocked by them.

If I use a VPN, I can actually get to the website from the device.

If I tether to the device from a PC and look at the tcp traffic, I can see that a UDP name server request for the website is repeatedly sent to the device, without reply.

Can anyone suggest a remedy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah two solutions I am aware of

1. Cause: improper configuration of IPV6 from ISP
   Solution: Go to APN settings and disable IP V6 (set apn protocol to ipv4 from ipv4/v6 and save the current APN)
2. Cause: DNS issue
   Solution: Change DNS settings to Google's DNS or anything else (it's called 'private DNS' in some devices under settings)

Comment: 1. APN was already set to IP4 only. 2. Changed DNS setting to private from default automatic. Problem prevails.

Comment: Edit: Can now access site directly on mobile device, but tethering access problem remains!

Comment: Go to wifi/system settings of client device and tweat dns there too!

Comment: I cannot get the client PC to resolve the name no matter what I set the DNS setting on the PC's wifi interface to be (custom private or automatic).  Is it possible that the android hotspot function always uses the ISP's DNS?

Comment: Finally got the PC side to work.  But I had to do it through the _browser's_ DNS over HTTPS setting.  All very strange.